# The pipeline never runs when there are job dependencies

Tags: gitlab-ci

When a job needs other jobs to be completed in order to run, and the previous one has a condition, the pipeline doesn't run.

So, in this scenario, when I commit into master, the entire pipeline runs fine, but when the pipeline is triggered by the scheduler, it doesn't.

```
independent_job:
  stage: independent_job
  script:
    - echo "running a random job"
  only:
    refs:
      - master


job1:
  stage: job1
  script:
    - echo "this is job1"
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  except:
    variables:
    - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"


job2:
  stage: job2
  needs:
    - job1
  script:
    - echo "this is job2"
  only:
    refs:
      - master
```

Since the second job needs the first one to run, and the first one won't run as the pipeline is triggered by scheduler, the entire pipeline doesn't run.

What I want to happen is the `independent_job` to run regardless, since it is not tied to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `when: always` to the definition of `independent_job` like so:

```
independent_job:
  stage: independent_job
  script:
    - echo "running a random job"
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  rules:
    when: always
```

There is more explanation here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html